# Google Web designer

Tags: gnome-terminal, libraries, error-handling, web-design

everyone. I am new to ubuntu user

I got this response after ~$ google-webdesigner

```
google-webdesigner
google-webdesigner: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks you

Comment: How did you install google-webdesigner?

Comment: Did you already try "sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4" ? a .so file is kind of like a .dll, it is a library but you can just install them using apt-get in the terminal (press CTRL+ALT+T to get a terminal)

Comment: - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-webdesigner_current_amd64.deb

- sudo dpkg -i google-webdesigner_current_amd64.deb @muclux

Comment: @Marco Septian i am glad i could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by first removing this package once:

```
sudo apt purge google-webdesigner
```

Then install `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

then install your package again with `gdebi`:

```
sudo gdebi google-webdesigner_current_amd64.deb
```

This will automatically install all needed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

We only need to install libgconf-2.4

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2.4
```

From a [solution posted by portm](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gwdbeta/Obx7OvYKleY/sdVTZwL3AwAJ) on 2018, 14 Jun Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.